# data is not showing dynamically in modal window with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have one modal window in which I am fetching data dynamically with the help of Ajax functionality, but data is not shown in the modal window.

Following is the HTML code for modal window.

```
<div id="tariffdetailModal" class="modal show fade" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title">Dynamic Data</h6>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="tmcode" id="tmcode" />
      <div class="modal-body pt-1">
        <div class="control-container" id="tariffdetail_data"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is the JavaScript code for loading data with Ajax function.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tariffdetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var tmcode = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book_id').tmcode;
      $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="tmcode"]').val(tmcode);
      load_data();
    });

    function load_data(){
         $.ajax({
              url:"tariffdetaildata.php",
              method:"POST",
              //async: true,
              data:{},
              success:function(data){
                   $('#tariffdetail_data').html(data);
              }
         });

    }
  })
</script>
```

Following is the php page for data which is called in the Ajax function....

```
<?php
    $output=''; 
    $output .='<input type="text" name="abcd" value="abcd" />';
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Make sure that there is no other elements in the page with same ID `tariffdetail_data` by using inspect or from source

Comment: Does console logs any error?

Comment: only showing Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/egp/style/css/bootstrap.min.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map

Comment: tariffdetaildata.php put this file

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `var tmcode = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book_id').tmcode;`. Where's the attribute "book_id" coming from? `.data('book_id)` may be returning undefined or an empty value. Check that.

Comment: actually this variable is coming from the anchor tag which is opening the modal window the code is  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tariffdetailModal" data-book_id='{"tmcode":"12345"}' class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>More Details</a>

Comment: actually i checked its returning correct value and i changed the value to "12345" just to make it simple but it is getting the value for this variable from database. and i checked with alert(tmcode) and its returning correct value

Comment: I just need to get the $output data into tariffdetail_data div.

Comment: i still think you need to check the values there. what's the value of the `e.relatedTarget`?. also check this `data-book_id='{"tmcode":"12345"}'`. You are returning a direct string from the data attribute and not parsing it before calling `('book_id').tmcode`. you can make it simple like `data-book_tmcode='12345'`

Comment: check console to see if there's an error with  the ajax call